# Funding Native Mint: Sum of account balances before and after instruction do not match

Tags: anchor, solana-program, spl-token, rust, spl-associated-token-account

I'm trying to fund a Native Mint token Account from a PDA and then Sync it like so.

```
    **(funder.try_borrow_mut_lamports()?) -= excess_sol;
    **(wrapped_sol_escrow.try_borrow_mut_lamports()?) += excess_sol;

    anchor_spl::token::sync_native(CpiContext::new(ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(), 
      anchor_spl::token::SyncNative{ account: wrapped_sol_escrow.to_account_info() }))?;
```

But this gives "Sum of account balances before and after instruction do not match"

Answer (score 3):

I asked [a similar question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8907/pda-rent-exemption-collection-to-transaction-fee-payer-error-on-account-close) recently.

You need to transfer the balance at the very end of your transaction, or at least after any Cross Program Invocation.

See [this github issue](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/9711) that explains why.

Comment: Yep I saw your question but in this example it woudn't work as I need to sync in the native mint balance to be usable.

Comment: Then I guess you’d have to do it in two transactions instead of one until the bug is fixed? (Assuming it is fixed one day considering that it’s already pretty old…)